# Fill down Index Match Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=INDEX($E2:$E$300,MATCH("PE",$D2:$D$300,0))
=INDEX($E2:$E$300,MATCH("CE",$D2:$D$300,0))
```

I am using above 2 formulas to extract data from `E2:E300`for matching two words like `CE` and `PE`. which is situated in column `D2:D300`. I want result for `PE` in column `F2` and drag down. Another `CE` result want in column `G2`and down. But the `CE` word starts from `row` above `100` and when I drag it in column `G2` and down I am getting incorrect match. But getting correct result for `PE`.

Comment: Have you tried changing $E2 to $E$2 and $D2 to $D$2 before copying down?

Comment: Thanks Aeneas. Tried but result blank rows or not any figure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search CE from row 100 down, then the formula should be:

`=INDEX($E100:$E$300,MATCH("CE",$D100:$D$300,0))`

Comment: Yes, currently doing same, but has to keep on change because raw data keep on changing, sometimes from row 90 sometimes from row 116.